# How to get the first index of a pandas DataFrame for which several undefined columns are not null?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe with several columns. I want to get the first row index for which:

- the value of column A is not null
- there exists at least n other columns for which the values are not null

example: if my dataframe is:

```
          Date          A             B      C     D
0   2015-01-02          NaN           1      1    NaN
1   2015-01-02          NaN           2      2    NaN
2   2015-01-02          NaN           3      3    NaN
3   2015-01-02          1            NaN     4    NaN
5   2015-01-02          NaN           2      NaN  NaN
6   2015-01-03          1            NaN     6    NaN
7   2015-01-03          1             1      6    NaN
8   2015-01-03          1             1      6     8
```

If n=1 I would get 3

If n=2 I would get 7

If n=3 I would get 8

Comment: Why for n=1, you would get 6 and not 3?

Comment: Mea culpa, you're right, post edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one approach to get those indices for different `n's` in one go -

```
def numpy_approach(df, reference='A'):
    df0 = df.iloc[:,df.columns != 'Date']
    valid_mask = df0.columns != reference
    mask = ~np.isnan(df0.values)
    count = mask[:,valid_mask].sum(1) * mask[:,(~valid_mask).argmax()]
    idx0 = np.searchsorted(np.maximum.accumulate(count),[1,2,3])
    return df.index[idx0]
```

Sample runs -

```
In [555]: df
Out[555]: 
         Date    A    B    C    D
0  2015-01-02  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN
1  2015-01-02  NaN  2.0  2.0  NaN
2  2015-01-02  NaN  3.0  3.0  NaN
3  2015-01-02  1.0  NaN  4.0  NaN
5  2015-01-02  NaN  2.0  NaN  NaN
6  2015-01-03  1.0  NaN  6.0  NaN
7  2015-01-03  1.0  1.0  6.0  NaN
8  2015-01-03  1.0  1.0  6.0  8.0

In [556]: numpy_approach(df, reference='A')
Out[556]: Int64Index([3, 7, 8], dtype='int64')

In [557]: numpy_approach(df, reference='B')
Out[557]: Int64Index([0, 7, 8], dtype='int64')

In [558]: numpy_approach(df, reference='C')
Out[558]: Int64Index([0, 7, 8], dtype='int64')

In [568]: numpy_approach(df, reference='D')
Out[568]: Int64Index([8, 8, 8], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: I get the following error while running it:     `result = getitem(key)
IndexError: index 50 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 50`

Comment: @Arty Could there be a case, where we don't have 3 columns that are not all null? Just edited few things in the codes. Could you run using it and tell me at which line you might be getting that error?

Comment: Yes indeed, I haven't precise that case. Neither did I precise the case where the target column is not A but B for example, in that last case how to do ?

Comment: @Arty If I understood your comment, you want to use `B` column as the reference and use all other columns after that? If so, edit : `colA_idx = np.argmax(df.columns == 'B')` i.e. getting the column ID of `B` and then using the same code.

Comment: Nop I mean using columns B as reference and all other columns before AND after  column B.

Comment: @Arty Don't you have `Date` as one column? If so, won't you want to skip that column from the computations?

Comment: Sorry I forgot about the date column. Let's say it does not exist or that we want to skip it.

Answer (score 3):

You can first select by `A` where not `NaN` and columns for count by `loc`, then get `sum` per row of [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.notnull.html) values with substract `1` for column `A`.

Last use boolean mask with [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html):

```
a = df.loc[df['A'].notnull(), 'A':].notnull().sum(axis=1).sub(1)
print (a)
3    1
6    1
7    2
8    3
dtype: int64

N = 1
print ((a == N).idxmax())
3

N = 2
print ((a == N).idxmax())
7

N = 3
print ((a == N).idxmax())
8
```

---

```
print (df.loc[df['A'].notnull(), 'A':])
     A    B    C    D
3  1.0  NaN  4.0  NaN
6  1.0  NaN  6.0  NaN
7  1.0  1.0  6.0  NaN
8  1.0  1.0  6.0  8.0
```

Comment: Your answer only works if column A is the first column but what if there are other columns before ?

Comment: Hmmm, do you count columns from `A` to the end of `df`? (`B,C,D`, ... columns?)

Comment: and column `A` in your sample is second, `print (df.loc[df['A'].notnull(), 'A':])` not return columns for count (also there is column `A` with always non NaN values, so `sub(1)` substract it).

Comment: I think you mis understood my comment. I meant what if the target column is not A anymore but B for example, ie there are columns before and after?
What if there are no 1 but something else in column A ?

Comment: It works also nice. `print (df.loc[df['B'].notnull(), 'B':])` and get all columns from `B` to `end`, if need columns from starts and end also, `print (df[df['B'].notnull()])`.